# How to test application using app authenticity enabled on remote worklight server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, rational-test-workbench

We are trying to test our IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation-based mobile application with IBM Rational Test Workbench MobileTest version 8.7.

One issue we are running into is that the testing fails due to application authenticity tests failure when trying to test against a remote worklight server. We tried to test it locally and that works. However, we are wondering if turning off the app authenticity is the only way to test using a remote worklight server. If anyone knows of any setting etc to get around the issue without having to turn off app authenticity every time we test on a pre-production build ( using remote server ) please let us know. It will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

There are no settings.

I can think of two ways:

1. Either authenticity is enabled, and the server and client are properly setup for the authenticity challenge to successfully pass...
2. Or you disable it for example by temporarily commenting out the wl_authenticity realm from the used security test in the authenticationConfig.xml file (which is located inside the .war file that was deployed to the remote server). Once done testing, uncomment it and re-start the server.

Comment: Thanks Idan. Regarding #1 just to clarify - client and server are setup correctly. When the application is run directly on the phone against a remote server, there are no app authenticity issues/failure. However, when we run it using the Rational Test Workbench the app fails and logs show authenticity failure. We are guessing it is due to the fact that the server is throwing a challenge to the rational workbench app that wraps our app and the response is not as expected. When running it against local dev server, since there is no app authenticity, so it runs without issues.

Comment: ...continued..  So we were wondering if there was known way to tackle it without turning app authenticity off as this has got to be an issue anytime anyone uses workbench. Per your answer seems like there isn't any and turning off app authenticity is only way to test with workbench and remote server.

Comment: If the app is modified in any way by RTW, it will fail (which means the feature works :). There is no way around it other than to disable it.